# Paperclip providing wrong URL when using S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

The correct url is: http://s3.dvulgsolucoes.com.br/folder/filename.png and I'm getting this url: http://s3.dvulgsolucoes.com.br.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/filename.png

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: 'bucketname.com.br',
    access_key_id: '###',
    secret_access_key: '###',
  }
}

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/clients/dmg/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default URL and path from paperclip, editing paperclip.rb on initializer:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

You can check this link from Heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#configuration